# ${userRole} in jsp under Tomcat 7.0 does not evaluate correctly

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

JSP page under Tomcat 7.0:

I have a database set up that Tomcat can communicate with and perform authentication.

Problem: `${userRole}` in a JSP does not seem to work properly. It appears that `${userRole}` evaluates correctly to 'user' and 'admin' when those are the role entries in the database for the user in question. However, if the role is anything else, e. g. 'abcd', then the role evaluates to 'user'.

Below is a list of user's role in the database and what `${userRole}` evaluates to in the JSP:

```
role in db  ${userRole} in jsp
1234        user
adm         user
abcd        user
user        user
admin       admin
```

Why does `${userRole}` not evaluate correctly when the role is something else than user and admin?
Is `${pageContext.request.isUserInRole('roleName')}` the only way to make decisions based on role assignments?

Comment: What do you expect when a user is in multiple rows?

Comment: No. It is not in multiple rows. The table shows an entry in the DB (left) and what it evaluates to in JSP (right). One user has only one role at a time. There are no multiple rows.

Comment: looks like we'll need more information, e.g. full tables, configuration, etc. ("rows" in my previous comment should have been "roles", sorry. Not sure if it was my personal autocorrect or that of my computer/phone). However, as technically a user *could* be in multiple roles, I wouldn't expect an API to reveal a single user role, unless you explicitly enumerate.